# JavaScript RegEx for Phone Number that allows for # sign, but not alpha characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to build a javascript regex for phone number.

I currently have this...but it is failing.

```php
^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})?[#. ]?([0-9]{10})$
```

Examples:

```
(555) 555-1212 - Acceptable 
(555) 555-1212 #12525 - Acceptable (Up to 10 digits after the # sign)
5555551212 - Acceptable
555-555-1212 - Acceptable
555-555-1212 #12525 - Acceptable (Up to 10 digits after the # sign)
```

Any alpha characters should be Unacceptable

```
(555) 555-1212 ext 12525 - Unacceptable
(555) 555-1212 x12525 - Unacceptable
```

Regex has been a weak area of mine and I am not sure how to make it work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate phone numbers using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/how-to-validate-phone-numbers-using-regex)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})(?:[-. ]?([0-9]{4}))?(?:[#. ]+([0-9]{1,10}))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AxlIvy/2).

Main points are: 1) turning `[#. ]?` into `[#. ]*` because there can be both spaces and `#` (or maybe `.`, too) before the coming digits, and 2) `[0-9]{10}` turning into `[0-9]{1,10}` to match one to ten digits.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\(?` - an optional `(`
- `([0-9]{3})` - Group 1: three digits
- `\)?` - an optional `)`
- `[-. ]?` - an optional delimiter
- `([0-9]{3})` - Group 2: three digits
- `(?:[-. ]?([0-9]{4}))?` - an optional sequence of an optional delimiter and four digits captured into Group 3
- `(?:[#. ]+([0-9]{1,10}))?` - an optional sequence of one or more delimiters and then one to ten digits captured into Group 4
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

This will match all of your test cases, but it can still fail if any of them are mixed.

```
\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?\d{3}[\-]?\d{4}( #\d{1,10})?
```

Your best bet would be to make a separate regex for each format you want to accept and then test the string against all of them to see if any match.

I recommend using a regex tester to see your query match in real time.

https://regex101.com/